# Gamepad detected, no buttons register

Tags: gamepad

I have a dreamgear shadow gamepad (DGPS3-3880).

Currently I'm trying to get RetroPie working in Ubuntu 20.04.

RetroPie recognises that a gamepad is plugged in, but won't register an
y of the buttons when pressed to set up the gamepad.

I've tried both xboxdrv and xpad drivers, and still have the same problem.

I've tried Batocera and Recalbox, and they have the exact same problem.

Is there any way to get this working on linux, or is my only option to make a windows emulation box (windows detects the gamepad just fine as plug-n-play).

Comment: Is the controller connected via USB or Bluetooth? If it's the former, can you edit the question to include the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: I only have the controller and keyboard attached.  
I'll include the output below in 2 posts as it's too big for one.
I tried including line breaks, but the "double space" the formatting guide told me to use seems to not be functioning.

Comment: Part1:  
  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 24ae:2010 Shenzhen Rapoo Technology Co., Ltd. Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device

Comment: Part 2:        
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: It's pretending to be an official Xbox 360 controller (`045e:028e`) which should allow it to work through `xpad`. If it's not working I'd expect to see an error from `xpad` in `dmesg` logs. `xboxdrv` won't work unless you've disabled the `xpad` module.